# Arcgis map graphics run hopelessly slow on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dictionary, internet-explorer-8, arcgis

I'm working on a project via arcgis javascript api.
With hundreds of graphics drawn on a graphicsLayer, it works well on chrome or IE11, but on IE8 and supposedly also IE6 when I drag the map, it's extremely slow so that makes it completely unusable. 
I found the "displayOnPan" option of graphicslayer which seems to be designed specifically for IE. But if I turn that off, the performance is still unsatisfactory, besides, the disappearing and reappearing of the graphics each time the map is panned are really irritating.

No question of requiring the users to update or change the browser.
Is there any ways to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to ESRI, no.  This is what I got from ESRI's support centre when I put the same question to them

*Hi Clark,*

*The Javascript API support for Internet Explorer 9 introduced significant performance improvements for drawing graphics.*

*In earlier versions of Internet Explorer, drawing large number of graphics performed poorly compared to browsers like Firefox and Chrome. At IE9, graphics drawing performance is much improved over earlier versions of IE and is comparable to other browsers.*

*A table comparing performance between the different browsers is available at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/new_v23.html*

*Feature services are essentially graphics. If the layer(s) you're loading contain a large number of features, this is the reason for slow performance in IE8.*